# Recursive CTE in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a table with the structure:

```
Employee_ID  Employee_Name  Manager_ID
```

And, for each employee, I need to show the top manager ID. I mean, if for example, I have the EmployeeID 2 whose manager is 3 and, therefore, the number 3 has the manager number 5, I would have to show:

```
Empoyee_ID--Top_Manager
2           5
```

I need to do this with a Recursive CTE in Postgres.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like (for the level 2 manager) :

```
WITH RECURSIVE T AS
(
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME, MANAGER_ID, 1 AS MANAGER_LEVEL
FROM   MyTable
UNION  ALL
SELECT T.EMPLOYEE_ID, T.EMPLOYEE_NAME, E.MANAGER_ID, MANAGER_LEVEL + 1
FROM   MyTable AS E
       JOIN T ON T.MANAGER_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE  T.MANAGER_LEVEL = 1 --> limiting to level 2 - 1
)
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME, MANAGER_ID
FROM   T 
WHERE  MANAGER_LEVEL = 2 --> retrieving only level 2, not level 1 and 2
```

Answer (score 3):

That's a typical recursive query. Here is one way to do it in Postgres:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select 1 lvl, employee_id, manager_id from mytable
    union all
    select c.lvl + 1, c.employee_id, t.manager_id
    from cte c
    inner join mytable t on t.employee_id = c.manager_id 
)
select distinct on (employee_id) employee_id, manager_id top_manager
from cte c
order by employee_id, lvl desc
```

The cte climbs up the hierarchy while keeping track of the original employee id and of the relationship level. The outer query filters on the top manager per employee.