# get items from one-level tree postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data

I have one-level tree structure like

```
create table comment (id integer not null, parent_id integer);
```

parent_id references to "id" the same table.
I am sure that hierarchy will have not more than 1 level.
I need to get filtered elements with their parents as list (id, parent_id)
I tried this query, but it didn't work:

```
select *
from comment c1
union select * from comment c2 where c2.Id = c1.parent_id
```

recursive doesn't suit bcz its one level

Comment: research "recursive CTE" e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59692974/recursive-cte-in-postgres

Comment: recursive doesnt suit because its one level tree

Comment: If it's only one level, then a self join would do

Comment: if recursion is overkill then self join as mentioned above `select * from comment c join comment p on c.parent_id = p.id`

Comment: that request returns 4: id, id1, parent_id, parent_id1 columns instead of required result(children + parents as rows)

Comment: @PaulMaxwell i solved it:
`WITH query AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM comment
    WHERE id = 2
)

select * from query q
union select c.id, c.parent_id from comment c
where c.id = any(select parent_id from query)`

Comment: Happy you have a solution but it is unnecessarily complex. A self join will achieve the same more efficiently.

Comment: @PaulMaxwell Did you try that request? If not, please try and compare with result from my query. You will be surprised

Comment: How would I try your "request"? I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)